# Instaling ubuntu via usb?

Tags: usb

Newbie user Question :1 (oh yes there will be more)
After being shafted by Microsoft I am now unable to use my cd/dvd drive. Can I download & Install Ubuntu via usb/memory stick?
I have 3 partitions on my PC 149GB (with windows)/ 763GB Data and 17GB (new volume).
I have an ASUS ET2221A all in one PC

Answer (score 0):

Yes, refer to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick). You will need to create the bootable USB stick on another machine first though (or the same machine if it is already running Windows).

Comment: Thank you for the help & advice. now up and running, Cheers Col.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed install Ubuntu with USB, and I rather use a USB stick over a CD drive. Using a USB stick to install goes way faster than with a DVD.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'm up and running and have managed to add flash player, spotify and other bits.  Cheers Col.